# How to put a custom form region in Outlook's appointment 'schedule' pane?

Tags: .net, vsto, outlook-2007

It's pretty easy to show a custom form in Outlook 2007 'Appointment' pane using VSTO (Form Region of the `IPM.Appointment` type).

So far, so good. But I'd like to put my form not on the first 'Appointment' pane, but rather on bottom of the 'Schedule' pane.

Any idea?

Comment: Can you show a picture of what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems it's not possible, period.